# React router not re-rendering route container after query params update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Here I am having `/products/mobile` route

[image]

After clicking on filter I am doing route.push using react-router-redux

[image]

Here It seems react-router-redux firing location change action, but its not re-rendering any view(Page stays constant without calling component remount with new params).It's just updating url in browser.

[image]

I am using `this.props.router.push(/products/mobile?manufacturer=Apple)`
to make route transition.

Comment: why you want it to re-render when you already have ability to perform actions when user selects the filter? you can use  replace method to update the location

Answer (score 0):

checking the [react router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md) maybe you should try with:

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/products/mobile',
  query: { manufactuerer: 'Apple' }
})
```

let me know.